# How do I verify mockito calls in asynchronous methods

Tags: scala, mockito, promise, future, specs2

I'm writing a highly asynchronous bit of code and I'm having problems testing it using Specs2 and Mockito.  The problem is that the matchers are executed before the asynchronous code executes.  I see that specs2 has `await` and `eventually` helpers - they look promising but I'm not sure how to use them.

Below is a stripped down example that illustrates the problem

**SUT**

```
package example.jt

import scala.concurrent._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

trait Service {
  def foo 
  def bar 
  def baz 
}

class AnotherTest(svc: Service) {

  def method(fail: Boolean) {
    svc.baz
    future {
      Thread.sleep(3000)
      pvt(fail) onComplete {
        case Success(_) => svc.foo
        case Failure(ex) => svc.bar
      }   
    }   
  }

  private def pvt(fail: Boolean):Future[Unit] = { 
    val p = Promise[Unit]

    future {
      Thread.sleep(2000)
      if (fail) p failure (new RuntimeException("Failure"))
      else p success ()
    }   

    return p.future
  }
}
```

**Specs2 Test**

```
package example.jt.test

import example.jt._
import org.specs2.specification._
import org.specs2.mutable._
import org.specs2.specification._
import org.specs2.mutable._
import org.specs2.mock._

class TestPromise extends Specification with Mockito {

  "mocks in promises" should {
    "Verify foo" in {
      val svc = mock[Service]
      val sut = new AnotherTest(svc)

      sut.method(false)
      there was one(svc).baz
      there was one(svc).foo
      there was no(svc).bar
    }   

    "Verify bar" in {
      val svc = mock[Service]
      val sut = new AnotherTest(svc)

      sut.method(true)
      there was one(svc).baz
      there was one(svc).bar
      there was no(svc).foo
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You simply need to wait on your future calls. Either by using [`Await`](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html) directly:

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

Await(sut.method(false), 10 seconds)
```

or by using `.await` on a matcher (look for `await` in the [matchers guide](http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Matchers.html#Matchers)):

```
sut.method(false) must not(throwAn[Exception]).await
```

Comment: How do I use Await directly?